# Establecer top de un div en relacion a la pantalla

Tags: javascript, html5, css

tengo un div que aparece al tocar un boton de abrir (similar a un modal), este boton aparece n veces a lo largo de la página, mi problema es que si se ha hecho scroll hacia abajo y se hace clic en el boton de abrir, el div aparece en la parte superior de la pagina y el usuario debe hacer scroll hacia arriba para poder verlo, ¿como podria establecer que el top de ese div este en relacion a la parte superior de la pantalla al momento de abrirlo y no de la pagina para que siempre sea visible sin tener que subir de nuevo? por ultimo no tengo permitido usar bootstrap, agradeceria una respuesta con css o javascript.

este es el estilo que tiene el div por ahora:

```
dialog {
 z-index: 1000;
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 20px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 min-height: 200px;
 width: 90%;
 height: 95vh;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 max-width: 520px;
}
```

Nota: he intentado establecer el top con

> px, %, vh y vw

pero no he tenido buenos resultados, el top siempre se mantiene fijo una vez establecido.

Comment: ese tipo modal deberia cubrir toda la pantalla?

Comment: Con el CSS que compartes, he creado un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6gxdx4vx/) y no puedo reproducir el problema que comentas. ¿Podrías incluir un [mcve] en la pregunta para que podamos ver qué y cómo está fallando?

Comment: Con `position: fixed` le das una posición **fija** a un elemento relativo al viewport, por ende, si haces scroll éste se mantendrá en la misma posición. Otra opción es hacerlo `absolute` y mediante JavaScript obtener el `scrollTop` y el `scrollLeft` del elemento para así centrarlo y ejecutar éstos cálculos en el evento `scroll`.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro revise su JSFiddle y funciona, ahora se me complica subir un ejemplo, estoy usando angular 2 y ese div esta dentro de un componente que importo desde otro, pensé que el problema era solo css pero segun lo visto angular podria tener algo que ver

Comment: @guzgarcia intentare utilizar el scrollTop, gracias por el dato

Comment: utilice el scrollTop del body y a ese valor le sume los px del margen superior que necesitaba para que no aparezca pegado a la parte superior y funciona, gracias por la ayuda, por cierto, no fue necesario cambiar la posicion a absolute

Comment: @guzgarcia si gusta puede responder la pregunta para marcar su resuesta como la que me ayudo y que reciba los puntos de reputacion

Comment: @AndrésChamorro He publicado mi respuesta y agregado más información al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `position: fixed` le das una **posición fija** a un elemento **relativo al viewport**, por ende, si haces scroll éste se mantendrá en la misma posición. Otra opción es hacerlo `absolute` y mediante JavaScript obtener el `scrollTop` y el `scrollLeft` del elemento para así centrarlo y ejecutar éstos cálculos en el evento `scroll` de window.

**Usando** `position: fixed`

Hay un problema con usar éste método: **si el alto del elemento supera al viewheight, la parte que se desborda no será visible**. Ejecuta el siguiente ejemplo para reproducir el problema:

```js
let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
let width = modal.offsetWidth;
let vw = window.innerWidth;

/* centra la ventana modal horizontalmente */
modal.style.marginLeft = `${(vw - width) / 2}px`;
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url('http://www.awwwards.com/awards/images/2013/10/Free_People.jpg') repeat-y;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 500vh;
}
.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 5;
}
.modal .head {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .head .title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .head .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}
.modal .body {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal .body h2 {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .body p {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.modal .foot {
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .foot .btn { margin-left: 10px; }
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
.btn.default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
.btn.primary {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <header class="head">
      <h3 class="title">Oferta</h3>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </header>
    <article class="body">
      <h2>¡Aproveche nuestras ofertas!</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam porro, hic facilis pariatur maxime praesentium doloribus, esse iste enim distinctio ipsa nobis reiciendis aut similique, eligendi illum, quibusdam nam repellat.
      </p>
    </article>
    <footer class="foot">
      <button class="btn default">Cerrar</button>
      <button class="btn primary">Aceptar</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Usando** `position: fixed` **y** `max-height`

El anterior problema lo puedes solucionar dando un `max-height` al modal **para que no supere el viewport** en ningún momento. Además, en caso quieras poner un margen, se **resta el margen superior e inferior al viewport**. Ésto puedes hacerlo vía `calc` o, en caso quieras dar soporte a navegadores viejos, puedes hacerlo mediante JavaScript. Ejecuta el suguiente ejemplo para ver su funcionamiento.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  let width = modal.offsetWidth;
  let vw = window.innerWidth;

  /* centra la ventana modal horizontalmente */
  modal.style.marginLeft = `${(vw - width) / 2}px`;
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url('http://www.awwwards.com/awards/images/2013/10/Free_People.jpg') repeat-y;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 500vh;
}
.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 800px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  max-width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 5;
}
.modal .head {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .head .title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .head .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}
.modal .body {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal .body h2 {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .body p {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.modal .foot {
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .foot .btn { margin-left: 10px; }
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
.btn.default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
.btn.primary {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <header class="head">
      <h3 class="title">Oferta</h3>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </header>
    <article class="body">
      <h2>¡Aproveche nuestras ofertas!</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam porro, hic facilis pariatur maxime praesentium doloribus, esse iste enim distinctio ipsa nobis reiciendis aut similique, eligendi illum, quibusdam nam repellat.
      </p>
    </article>
    <footer class="foot">
      <button class="btn default">Cerrar</button>
      <button class="btn primary">Aceptar</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Usando** `position: fixed` **y** `max-height` **vía JS**

La regla `calc` [tiene una aceptación bastante buena](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) ahora mismo así que se puede usar sin ningún remordimiento. Sin embargo, si tu público final puede tener navegadores muy viejos como IE < 9, entonces es probable que quieras hacerlo compatible. Paa ésto puedes establecer el alto máximo de la modal de acuerdo al viewheight **incluso cuando se redimensione** la ventana.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  adjustModal();
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', adjustModal);
});

function adjustModal () {
  let modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
  let width = modal.offsetWidth;
  let vw = window.innerWidth;
  let vh = window.innerHeight;
  
  /* centra la ventana modal horizontalmente */
  modal.style.marginLeft = `${(vw - width) / 2}px`;
  /* Le da un alto máximo al modal */
  modal.style.maxHeight = `${vh - 40}px`;
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: url('http://www.awwwards.com/awards/images/2013/10/Free_People.jpg') repeat-y;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 500vh;
}
.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal .head {
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .head .title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .head .close {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
}
.modal .body {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal .body h2 {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.modal .body p {
  font-family: 'segoe ui', 'ubuntu', 'noto sans', system;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.modal .foot {
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
.modal .foot .btn { margin-left: 10px; }
.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
}
.btn.default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
}
.btn.primary {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal">
    <header class="head">
      <h3 class="title">Oferta</h3>
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </header>
    <article class="body">
      <h2>¡Aproveche nuestras ofertas!</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam porro, hic facilis pariatur maxime praesentium doloribus, esse iste enim distinctio ipsa nobis reiciendis aut similique, eligendi illum, quibusdam nam repellat.
      </p>
    </article>
    <footer class="foot">
      <button class="btn default">Cerrar</button>
      <button class="btn primary">Aceptar</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Puedes verlo en funcionamiento más cómodamente en [éste Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/0ezu0fa7/).

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente crearía un contenedor para tu `div.dialog` que ocupe el 100% del `window` y así evitar que el usuario pueda clickar en otro botón mientras tu dialogo esté visible. Dentro de este contenedor te será bastante fácil posicionar un `div` centrado.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
.dialog-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dialog {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```